# MYSQL - Get values from the last id in a group by query

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, left-join

Full example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/349b52/3/0)
I have a query from 3 tables

```
SELECT MAX(s.id_stock), s.precio_in, s.codigo, 
   SUM(s.cantidad) - COALESCE(sv.suma_salidas,0) as cantidad, 
   x.status
    FROM db1_stock s
    LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT COALESCE(sum(cant_ser),0) suma_salidas, codigo
       FROM db1_servicios
       GROUP BY codigo) sv USING (codigo)       
    LEFT JOIN db1_oc x
        ON (s.oc_id = x.oc_id)
    WHERE x.status = 'EN BODEGA'
    GROUP BY s.codigo
    ORDER BY x.fecha_oc DESC
```

Tables (db1_services is empty)

[image]
[image]

Result
[image]

I expect the same result, but from the last `id_stock`, without losing the SUM and group by `codigo`; not the max value of `precio_in`, just the most recent. Thanks !!
[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/349b52/3/0)

Comment: thanks for including a fiddle - it makes answering the question *so* much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last value of `precio_in` (I presume meaning the one associated with `MAX(id_stock)`) you need to do the aggregation on `db1_stock` in a derived table and then `JOIN` that back to `db1_stock`:

```
SELECT s.id_stock, 
       s.precio_in, 
       s.codigo, 
       a.cantidad - COALESCE(sv.suma_salidas,0) as cantidad, 
       x.status
FROM db1_stock s
JOIN (
  SELECT codigo,
         MAX(id_stock) AS id_stock,
         SUM(cantidad) AS cantidad
  FROM db1_stock
  GROUP BY codigo
) a ON a.codigo = s.codigo AND a.id_stock = s.id_stock
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COALESCE(SUM(cant_ser),0) AS suma_salidas, codigo
  FROM db1_servicios
  GROUP BY codigo
) sv ON sv.codigo = s.codigo
JOIN db1_oc x ON s.oc_id = x.oc_id
WHERE x.status = 'EN BODEGA'
ORDER BY x.fecha_oc DESC
```

Output:

```
id_stock    precio_in   codigo      cantidad    status
19          4000        PRUEBA      6           EN BODEGA
20          4200        PRUEBA2     1           EN BODEGA
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/349b52/5)

Comment: Just Perfect!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following, and note, not a picture in sight.

```
     SELECT x.id_stock 
          , x.codigo  
          , x.precio_in
          , x.cantidad 
          , o.status    
       FROM db1_stock x 
       JOIN db1_oc o
         ON o.oc_id = x.oc_id 
       JOIN 
          ( SELECT codigo
                 , MAX(id_stock) id_stock 
              FROM db1_stock 
             GROUP 
                BY codigo
          ) y 
         ON y.codigo = x.codigo 
        AND y.id_stock = x.id_stock;
+----------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| id_stock | codigo  | precio_in | cantidad | status    |
+----------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|       19 | PRUEBA  |      4000 |        3 | EN BODEGA |
|       20 | PRUEBA2 |      4200 |        1 | EN BODEGA |
+----------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Your `cantidad` value is incorrect (yes - it is hard to read in  the picture!). Note OP sums it in their original query and I have summed it in my derived table.

Comment: @Nick I see. Note that you also have `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =...`

Comment: You're right - copied that piece from OP. It will work as expected I think because it should be a JOIN (otherwise ordering by something in that table makes no sense) however I have corrected the answer to use an inner JOIN.